# /etc/shadow - how could it be edited when it is read only

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, filesystems, file-permissions

I am trying to change the content of /etc/shadow file but realize it is read only

```
sghk1> ls -l /etc/shadow
-r--------   1 root     sys         4045 Aug 19 16:13 /etc/shadow
```

the /etc/shadow file permission is read only. in that case how does /usr/bin/passwd change its contents ?

```
e.g. passwd -x 30 username
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root user in linux/unix systems can write to a file even if the write flag is not set. Therefore he can change the contents of `/etc/shadow` or any other file independent from it's permissions.

The `passwd` utility has the setuid bit set. See with:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/passwd
```

It should look like this:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 42824 Sep 13  2012 /usr/bin/passwd
```

Notice the `s` in the file owner permission. This indicates the [setuid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). If a normal user now executes the `passwd` utility, it is executed with the permission of the file owner; in this case root.

The setuid bit gains temporarily elevated privileges to run a specific task, such as changing things in system files, for example `/etc/shadow` or `/etc/passwd`.

The setuid bit must be handled with care. That mechanism can be used for several vulnerabilities if set on the wrong binary. Imagine, the `/bin/bash` utility would have set the setuid bit; so every user in the system could start a root shell!

Comment: I tried editing the /etc/shadow file directly using vi with a :wq, but I am not able to do that. the error it shows "shadow" File is read only
so how is /usr/bin/passwd able to write to the file ?

Comment: @Noob That's the editor that tries to warn that you edit a read only file (a file without the `w` flag). Use `:wq!`. vi should accept that.

Comment: what does ! actually meant in this sense, i always thought ! is use with q which means to quit without saving.

Comment: @Noob `:q!` forces to quit, without saving, `:w!` forces to save even when the file is readonly. `:wq!` is the same as `:w!` + close the editor.